# $rootScope.$broadcast not working on page refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, broadcast

I have an angularJs application(using ui-router) which needs to prevent users from accessing certain states unless they are logged in. In the applications .run block I'm checking if they are logged in. To help manage this I want to broadcast events to another controller of the same application.

Here's my(shortened) run block..

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {

  $rootScope.$broadcast('sessionExpired');

})

and the listener in my controller...

$scope.$on("sessionExpired", function() {

      console.log('goto login');

})
```

this works great when changing states after the application has loaded. But if I refresh the page, the .run block executes but the broadcast event is never received by the listener in the controller.

Any ideas why the event isn't received when refreshing the page?

Comment: you might need to put it inside of the `$transitions` service: `$transitions.onStart({}, ($transition$) => { ... $rootScope.$broadcast('sessionExpired'); ...}`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Thanks, I've tried placing the broadcast inside stateChangeStart but it's still not being received. Interestingly, I've tried with stateChangeSuccess and it IS being received, but I ideally want to check and resolve any authentification issues on stateChangeStart.